# Compiling an ASP .NET website into an executable (with server)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I remember many years ago using a program that would allow Classic ASP websites to be compiled into an .EXE and run as if they were under IIS. I used this program to create an interactive CD-ROM. Things like Request.QueryString() etc all worked as expected.

Does anyone know of a similar program that will do this for ASP.NET?

Thanks

Comment: I think the program you are thinking of is ActiveSite Compiler. You can download a trial [here](http://download.cnet.com/ActiveSite-Compiler/3000-2648_4-10199763.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UltiDev Web Server Pro](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx). Its a free redistributable web server but requires it to be installed in the client machine.

http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2832_UWS-Screenshots.aspx#post2832

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft calls it [Hosted Web Core Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :

> "Hosted Web Core is a new feature in IIS 7 that enables developers to create applications that load the core IIS functionality. Applications that load the Hosted Web Core use a separate configuration file from IIS, and this feature enables software developers to customize the functionality for their applications. For example, you can write an application that uses the Hosted Web Core functionality to serve Web pages and applications from a Web site that is separate from the Web sites that are hosted by IIS on the same server. When the World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW service) for IIS is recycled, your application will continue to serve Web pages to Web clients."

Comment: I have actually looked at this but as far as I can see IIS 7 is required to run a HWC application. I am looking for something that can run independently without IIS 7 so that is can be deployed on non professional versions of Windows i.e. XP Home, Windows 7 Basic..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you can pre-compile your application and ship it with [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038). But this won't be a single executable.